# Why are there no edge dislocations in a face-centered cubic (FCC) lattice?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

In crystallography, we know that the [Burgers vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers_vector) is parallel to the dislocation direction in a [screw dislocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation#Screw_dislocations), and perpendicular in a [edge dislocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation#Edge_dislocations).

Furthermore, I have in my lecture notes "[FCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face-centered_cubic) cannot have edge dislocations" but there is no explanation of why, aside from "in FCC, the Burger's vector belongs to the family of the dislocation direction vectors"

I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to stretch my memory to remember how this goes (and read a bit from [here](http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_5/backbone/r5_4_1.html)).

First, how do you define burgers vector? You take the end point of the dislocation and make a circle around it as it were a perfect lattice, the extra (or missing step) from the full loop is the burgers vector.

Now, is the burgers vector also a lattice vector? If yes, then it is (edge)dislocation. If no, then it is only a **partial** (edge)dislocation (partial dislocations have their own name).

Now, how does this work on a fcc-lattice case. On quick read for link I pasted, it seems that fcc-lattice cannot have edge dislocations, because the burgers vector is not a lattice vector.

You may want to go this through by yourself and check that I didn't make any mistakes.